# Sum of the unitary divisor function (mod p)

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

The sum of unitary divisors of a positive integer $n$ can be computed as $$ \sigma^\star(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}(p_i^{a_{\large i}}+1) $$ where $\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)} p_i^{a_{\large i}}$ is the prime factorisation of $n$; assuming that $\sigma^\star(1)=1$, being the empty product.

$\sum_{n=1}^x \sigma^\star(n)$ can either be computed exactly by factorising all numbers up to $x$, or it can be approximated as $\frac{\pi^2 x^2}{12\zeta(3)} + \mathcal{O}(x \thinspace log^{2/3}x)$.

For a prime $p \ll x$, how can we compute the *exact* modular sum $$ \sum_{\large n=1}^{\large x} \sigma^\star(n) \mod p $$ efficiently, doing fewer than $x$ prime factorisations?

Comment: I've found recursive formula for sum-of-unitary-divisors of even numbers in [Variant of a theorem of Erdős on the sum-of-proper-divisors function](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/uupaper6.pdf) by Carl Pomerance and Hee-Sung Yang ([journal link](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-288/S0025-5718-2013-02775-5/home.html)). But the way to handle odd numbers is unclear for me. An explanation would be great.